# JavaFX Root loading problems

Tags: javafx

I am relatively new to JavaFX. I am trying to test design pattern where each fxml has its own controller with loader.

Example:.

**text.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>

<VBox>
    <children>
        <Label text="Hello world FXML"/>
    </children>
</VBox>
```

**MainController**

```
public class MainController extends VBox {

    public MainController() {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/test.fxml"));
        loader.setController(this);
        try {
            loader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**App**

```
public class App extends javafx.application.Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        MainController mainController = new MainController();
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(mainController));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

This does not work, I get an empty window when application is started:

[image]

If make some changes to controller and App:

**controller**

```
private Parent root;

public MainController() {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/test.fxml"));
    loader.setController(this);
    try {
        root = loader.load();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Parent getRoot() {
    return root;
}
```

**App**

```
stage.setScene(new Scene(mainController.getRoot()));
```

After this everything works as expected, Label with text can be seen in window.

If I try to set root in controller:

```
loader.setRoot(this);
```

I get an error:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: Root value already specified.
/C:/.../target/classes/fxml/test.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2621)
    ...
```

**Question:** Can anyone with more experience in JavaFX advise me on this? What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

Since you're going for the *custom component* approach you need to make sure to:

- set `controller` and `root` for the `FXMLLoader` before loading the fxml in the constructor of your component
- use `<fx:root>` as root element of the fxml
- not specify `fx:controller` in the fxml

```xml
<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.VBox" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <children>
        <Label text="Hello world FXML"/>
    </children>
</fx:root>
```

```
public class MainController extends VBox {

    public MainController() {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/test.fxml"));
        loader.setController(this);
        loader.setRoot(this);
        try {
            loader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've read about this in https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/custom_control.htm#BABIGDEH, but I was hoping I could avoid having to use root and to specify type for it.

Comment: @CrazySabbath Well, either you want to access the properties of a node created outside of the fxml, which means you have to use `<fx:root>` or assemble the scene in java code. In this case you could change the fxml to simply contain the `Label` add the results of loading the fxml in the constructor, this gets more complicated, if you want to add multiple elements...

Answer (score -1):

In your first example you call 'loader.load()' but you're not using the return value of the method. You can try `this.getChildren().add(loader.load())`

As for the exception when calling `setRoot`, can you show all the relevant code?

Comment: All the code is the same, except setRoot call is added in Controller.

Comment: Where exactly do you add it? I'm asking because you should call it before calling `loader.load`

Comment: Yes, it's before load. To be clear: `setController(); setRoot(); load()`

Comment: As for not using return value, if you read further, you can see that I did exactly that, I just don't like that approach.